# Prevent table group footer starting on new page?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a table in a detail band and it consists of group footer as well.Data gets binding dynamically and grouped based on a column value.I'm displaying total in group footer.

Is there any way to prevent the group footer from starting a new page? If the group footer would normally be on its own at the start of the new page, then I'd rather bring one of the lines from the end of the previous page onto the new page as well.

Answer (score 3):

Report and dataset groups have an attribute called `preventOrphanFooter`.  Set it to `true` and the group footer will not be allowed to appear by itself in a page.  See some details [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#group_preventOrphanFooter).

The attribute is present in JasperReports 6.4.3 and newer.

Comment: thanks for the details.I'm using JasperReports 6.1.0. Let me try with the newer version.Btw attribute preventOrphanFooter works for column level group footer in a table?